# Fixed points of coset spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group. Let $\gamma$ be an automorphism of $G$, preserving a connected algebraic subgroup $H \subset G$. We have a map Writing $G^{\gamma} \subset G$ for the fixed point subgroup, etc. we have a map $G^{\gamma} / H^{\gamma} \rightarrow (G/H)^{\gamma}$.

When is this map an isomorphism (maybe on connected components)? I suspect this map is an open immersion, at least under reasonable natural conditions, by looking at the tangent spaces.